# pruebas en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Tengo un problema con un proyecto que me han dejado y es el siguiente, yo nunca he trabajado con test unitarios y demás. He seguido el manual de Laravel pero no consigo hacer funcionar las pruebas como las necesito, incluso he visto algunos tutoriales pero tampoco consigo hacerlo funcionar.

En el fichero de rutas distinto al web tengo esto. dentro de

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post'], function () {
        Route::post('/create','Api\PostController@create');
        Route::get('/remove','Api\PostController@remove');
        Route::post('/updatePost','Api\PostController@updatePost');
        Route::get('/showPost','Api\PostController@showPost');
    });
```

Estas y todas las rutas están dentro de otro group que es este

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function () {}
```

En el fichero de conroladores , en este caso de los post tendria un método, por ejemplo el showPost.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user =auth('api')->user();

    $user = new User();

    if ($user != null) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'Titulo',
            'content' => 'contenido',
            'author' => 1,
            'img_url'=>'',
            'tag_friends'=>'',
            'location'=>''

        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            $errors=array();
            $i=0;
            foreach ($validator -> errors()->messages() as $key=>$value)
            {
                $i+=1;
                $errors[]=[
                    'field'=>$key,
                    $i.'.'.'messages'=>$value[0],
                ];
            }
            return Response::json([
                "result"=>"error",
                "errors"=>$errors,
            ]);
        }

        $post=new Post();
        $user->id = $post->author();
        if($request->has('img_url')){
            $file=$request->img_url;
            $file->move(public_path().'/img/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $post->img_url='/img/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        }
        $post->contents=$request->contents;
        $post->tag_friends=$request->tag_friends;
        $post->location=$request->location;
        $post->saveOrFail();
        return Response::json([
            "result" => "ok",
            "message" => "Kayit Basarili",
        ]);
    }
    return Response::json([
        'error' => 'Unauthorised'
    ], 401);
}



}
```

En los test, he intentado trabajar con lo que encuentro en la documentacion pero no consigo hacerlo. como les dije nunca he trabajad con TDD como muchos y la verdad no se donde podría estar fallando.

El código de la prueba es este , la verdad no se si esta bien escrita ya que no controlo nada de pruebas unitarias por lo cual puede haber muchos fallos.

El error que me arroja dice `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`  y he probado incluso con el codigo que esta comentado pero no lgra correr

```
    public function testCreatePost()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $user = new \App\User(['email' => 'pepito@pepito.com']);

        auth()->login($user);

//        $response = $this->json('POST', '/post/create', ['user_id' => 1, 'contents' => 'contenido', 'tag_friends' => '' , 'author' => 1, 'img_url' => 'localhost/images/image.jpg' ]);
//
//        $response->assertStatus(200)
//            ->assertJson(['created' => true]);


        $this->post('/post/create/', ['author' => 1, 'content' => 'contenido', 'title' => 'titulo'  ])
            ->assertStatus(200)->assertJson(['created' => true]);

    }
```

Comment: Osea como podria quedar escrita la prueba unitaria y asi basarme para hacer todas las demas . Gracias

Comment: Y dónde está la prueba? Publicá lo que probaste. Te devuelve algún error?

Comment: explicar como usar TDD es bastante complicado por este medio. Te recomiendo mires alguno de los cursos que hay en youtube como introducción y hay muchísimo material sobre esta técnica. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tdd+laravel+espa%C3%B1ol+